# Ansible change string in multiple files

Tags: ansible

I have a folder with several sub folders and also files inside.  I need to change a string in all files at once. I can do for just one file but in other files in sub folders it does not affect them.

```
- name: Find all files with .json extension
      find:
        paths: /test/configuration/nginx/trials/{{ name }}/trial-admin-app/
        patterns: 'app-config.json'
      register: repos   



    - name:  Change string inside file    
      replace:
        dest: /test/configuration/nginx/trials/{{ name }}/trial-admin-app/                          #app-config.json    
        regexp: '{trial-name}'
        replace: '{{ name }}'
      with_items: "{{ repos.stdout_lines }}"
```

How do I change all files in the folder who also have sub folders?

Comment: You could use a combination of `find` with `sed` in the execute option.

Comment: I recommend _against_ `find` and `sed` in this case because you'll have to jump through hoops to make ansible aware of whether anything actually changed.  Idempotency should be properly represented in automation - it's important  to know whether things actually changed.    The module can do this fine, it just needs to be configured properly.  Use the tool how it's designed.  `ansible` is more sophisticated than a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

The `find` module you're using has a `recurse` parameter but it is off by default.

```
- name: Find all files with .json extension
      find:
        paths: /test/configuration/nginx/trials/{{ name }}/trial-admin-app/
        patterns: 'app-config.json'
        recurse: yes
      register: repos
```

By turning it on, I think you'll get the behavior you want.